# Optimización de la paginación

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Estoy tratando de usar la paginación para mostrar los posts por páginas, pero me parece que el resultado que tengo es demasiado engorroso y poco optimizado. Creo que podría mejorarse, me gustaría poder saber cómo implementarlo de mejor manera:

```
public async Task<ICollection<PostDTO>> GetAllByUserId(int userId, int lastId, int take)
        {
            try
            {
                ICollection<Post> posts = await _unitOfWork.Posts.GetAllIncluding(p => p.UserId == userId && p.IsDeleted == false);
                posts = posts.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
                Post lastPost = posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == lastId);
                int lastIndex = lastPost != null ? posts.ToList().IndexOf(lastPost) : 0;
                ICollection<Post> paginatedPosts = posts.Skip(lastIndex).Take(take).ToList();

                if (paginatedPosts.Count > 0)
                {
                    return (ICollection<PostDTO>)_mapper.Map<PostDTO>(paginatedPosts);
                }

                return new Collection<PostDTO>();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

La interfaz que uso para hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
 Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

Gracias de antebrazo.

Comment: Algunas observaciones: 1. Considera en utilizar CurrentPage y PageSize (esto se refiere a elementos por página). 2. ¿Y ese UnitOfWork está porque... ? 3. ¿Sí sabes que la pregunta tal cual está cae como basada en opiniones, verdad? 4. Siempre coloca un mensaje en las excepciones, te ayudará a depurar mucho mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Tu código tiene varias temas que se pueden mejorar, pero para entregar una respuesta, es necesario conocer la implementación de `GetAllIncluding`